# IOS Storyboard: Load Multiple Subviews for given position

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 3 different subviews all defined directly in the storyboard, so they have outlets to them as well. All of these subviews are meant to occupy the same coordinates on a screen at different times, with only one occupying the space at any time, so that it looks like some appearance is changing. How do I go about doing this? Say I also have a enumeration that defines what state I'm currently in and thus what subview is shown for that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic options:

1. Just go ahead and add the three subviews to your scene. If you do this, there are a couple of tricks that will make your life much easier in IB:

   - For each of the views, go to the "identity inspector" tab (the third one) in the far right panel, expand the "Document" section, and give each of the three views unique "labels" (not to be confused with `UILabel` controls; this is just a label or description that IB will use internally to refer to your view). That way, as you navigate the tree of controls listed in the "Document Outline" (that list of all of your scenes that appears in the left side of the center panel), you'll be able to figure out which is which. As you work with these overlapping views, a strong command of this "document outline" will make your life much easier.
   - When you have the three views on the scene, you may find that it will be easiest to drag the view you want to work on to the end of the list of the three views (but at the same level as its peers) in that "Document Outline". You can then edit that subview. Repeat that process for the three subviews as you do your IB work on them.
   - You can make an outlet collection for your three subviews, if you want. This makes it easier when you want to perform some action on all of the subviews. Perhaps not of great utility when dealing with only three, but if you ever had more subviews, the collections can be useful.
   - You can define unique `UIView` subclasses for each of the three views, which can be useful to keep your list of `IBOutlet` references a little more structured. Also any view-specific UI logic can be isolated into the individual `UIView` subviews.
   - If you use this technique, if you plan on animating the transition between these three subviews, it's actually quite useful to *not* just put these three subviews on the top-level view of the scene in question. It's quite useful to have a view on the scene that defines the dimensions of the three subviews, and then put your three subviews inside this new interim subview. This way, when you animate changes, you can constrain the animation to just that portion of the screen. This new, interim `UIView` is often called a container view, but should not be confused with the iOS 6 container view that you'll see in IB, which is related to the next technique, defined below.
2. While all of those tricks can make the manipulation and management of the three sets of overlapping views in a single scene a little easier, I actually think that a custom container view controller is the best way to go. One scene for the parent scene/view controller, and a separate view controller and IB scene for each of the three different child views. It takes a little extra code up front (not hard, but a little alien the first time you do it), but then your code and the IB scenes are nicely isolated. Architecturally, this is the most elegant approach, IMHO. If you want to do this, you should refer to:

   - WWDC 2011 #102 on [UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) (Apple developer ID required)
   - the [containment section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12) of the *View Controller Programming Guide*
   - the [containment section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) of the *UIViewController Reference* document