# Choose subview with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, subview

I have an iOS application with a subview, as well as a UISegmentedControl. I want to use my UISC to change subview1 to subview2. I decided to drag out a few more ViewControllers onto my storyboard, and put subview1 into the first, and subview2 in the second. After connecting the ViewControllers and making outlets for the subviews, I went back to my main ViewController (at this point there are three) and did

```
#import "SecondViewController"
SecondViewController *myView;
self.mySubview = myView.myOtherSubview;
```

but the subview on-screen didn't change. Is my template method of doing this totally wrong? If so, how would you suggest I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [UIView transitionFromView:toView...]

The basic idea is you'll have to child view controllers (check the docs in UIViewController under the child view controllers section) and transition from the view of one to the view of the other.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:

Answer (score 0):

This question, [IOS Storyboard: Load Multiple Subviews for given position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048576/ios-storyboard-load-multiple-subviews-for-given-position), is the same as mine, phrased better. The answer given there worked.